# Send an SMS message using Twilio from ManageEngine Eventlog Analyzer

Tags: https, parameters, twilio

I am setting up a computer system app which will send SMS alert. One can select:
Service type: HTTP, SMTP or SMPP.  I've been told to use HTTP.
HTTP(S) Method: Post or Get.  I've been told to use Get.
HTTP(S) URL: I believe that **https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01** is correct
HTTP(S) Parameters: gives an example:
username=xxx&password=xxxx&mobNo=%xxxx%&message=%[message]%
I am told that the "%" entries are just part of the mobNo and the message and are not to be entered separately.
I've been using:
username=[my Twilio logon email address]&password=[my Twilio pasword]&mobNo=[myTwiliomobNo]&message=testMessage
I get an error when I send a test message with this that says:
*"HTTP(S) parameters filed must contain %mobNo% and %message% for Mobile Number and Message fields"*
So, something must be wrong and I suspect the HTTPS parameters as there seems to be nothing else in question.
What should it be?

Comment: To send an SMS, you need a POST, not a GET.

Comment: The Eventlog Analyzer folks have confirmed that GET is the appropriate selection for their software.  Too bad one can't see inside.

Comment: I said: "I believe that https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01 is correct" but I'm no longer convinced.  Much closer to getting this done tho.  How would one find the HTTP(S) URL at Twilio?

Comment: Sending SMS Messages - https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages (you can look a CURL examples) to `Send an SMS Message`.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of documentation but correlating bits and pieces of it with what I'm given to work with is quite challenging.  Here is what I'm given to work with in this interface:

HTTP(S) URL 
Format:
Shown in gray: http://www.smsserver.com/sendsms

HTTP (S) Parameters: 
Shown in gray: username=xxx&password=vvv&mobileNumber=%mobNo%&message=%message%

And, I've tried to match these up with formats and data that I've found in Twilio docs but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I've been told that %mobNo% and %message% are like Windows command line parametes and should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

After discussion with both Twilio and EventLog Analyzer, it's been determined that the two are incompatible.

- EventLog Analyzer has a "canned" / programmed interface to the SMS provider, and
- Twilio can't accept the outputs.